Laravel inertia @vite hot reload on production issue
Hello everyone i just figure out if you dont delete hot file in public, laravel try to connect hot reload url.
Is this any automated way to handle this situation. When npm run build command executed it must be in production mode. Anyway what do you think about this situation. Is this normal or its just a bug. 3 Days ago i deploy website and its working properly. Last night i open the website and its have only default laravels page. After all of that check the files, logs etc.. Problem is hot file force laravel to dev mode.

Normally public/hot file should be in .gitignore, as it's something used only for local development. You don't need it in production. See the .gitignore file in official laravel/laravel repository for reference:
/.phpunit.cache
/node_modules
/public/build
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.env.production
.phpactor.json
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
auth.json
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
/.fleet
/.idea
/.vscode

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/76510a70c5b13b3facb2300ea7b1787342a7e0b0/.gitignore

Thats right! I was solved the problem but forgot the wrote here. I just used ftp and deleted hot file and its worked for me. Your answer is correct also
